# How to connect, by closest distance, vertices together in geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a bunch of points (vertices),

- they may, or may not be aligned to form a path
- they may, or may not be at regular interval distance from each other
- they have a completely random index value

[image]

How can i connect these points together in geometry node? either as a mesh type with edges or a curve, it does not matter

Comment: So are these vertices separate objects or one whole object?

Comment: Hi Yousuf, all verts are merged

Answer (score 4):

The logic on how to proceed:

1. get a urchin-like mesh, either create your own in geometry node with an icosphere or via edit mode

[image]

2. instance this urchin on every points and realize the instances, the scale factor of the instancing is very important, you'll use this to change the distance threshold
3. from here you can either do a merge by distance OR use the proximity node and set the position of your urchins vertices to closest position of the point cloud.

This is what such recipe looks like with the closest position method

[image]

or with the merge method

[image]

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: wow, nice, realy cool effect, looks like an object wrapped with wires (if you will convert it to curves and add some thickness)
thanx for sharing!