# Location Data to create Proxy Mesh for shadow catcher

Tags: shadows

I received the suggestion to use the location data to create a proxy mesh. Do they mean to eyeball the point cloud and draw out a plane? What's the best way to recreate part of the cliff to catch shadows?

Comment: [Point Cloud Visualizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXct_7k779Q) is nice helper with point clouds ... for meshing point cloud there is add-on [Skin Point Cloud](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/7wupp4zM3N9HUfZ75Qo366aXIo7.zip) for blender 3+ in [this thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/a-script-to-skin-a-point-cloud-for-blender-2-6x-or-later/529168/119) ... but it takes ages for complex cloud. It is better to use [Meshlab](https://www.meshlab.net) for [meshing point cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJRYEbO1YmA) Filters > Remeshing > Surface Reconstruction

Answer (score 0):

It depends how data looks like ... if you have just a location and rotation of single point, than it assume to be a just Camera info. So you can fake some environment (cliff) according to your real footage.

If your data is point cloud, than you can reconstruct environment (cliff) from these points. I would recommend **Meshlab** application (*Filters > Remeshing > Surface Reconstruction*), that is fast and accurate with minimum errors (for more info see my comment link).

Speaking to **Blender** - you can try import point cloud data.

[image]

And use this [Geometry Node's node group from BD3D](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268094/2214) to connect vertices by edges
(not perfect, but closest I found). Just adjust Threshold ...

[image]
[image]

*Apply* GN modifier and press F (*Fill*)

[image]

Ignore all errors and add **Remesh** modifier > *Voxel* ...

[image]

Comparison *Blender* vs *Meshlab* ... there is some lost of details but probably detailed enough for Shadow Catcher.

[image]